# Sockets - No data is shown on the client site

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to send data via `socket.io` to my client via nodejs.

The data I am receiving are from pusher.

I am using an express backend and loading my server like that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('testApp');
var app = require('../app');
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});


/**
 * return pusher data
 */

var API_KEY = 'cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f';
var pusher = new Pusher(API_KEY, {
    encrypted: true
});

/**
 * Socket.io
 */
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {log: true});

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // This will run when a client is connected

    // This is a listener to the signal "something"
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
        channel.bind("message", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    // This is a signal emitter called "something else"
    socket.emit("something else", {hello: "Hello, you are connected"});
});
```

On my client I am running the following script:

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js" />
    <script src='/javascripts/socket.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %> Juhu!</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

My **socket.js** file:

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    var total = data.total;

    //print data to console
    console.log(data);

});
```

My problem is that nothing gets shown in the console in my webbrowser, even though the data is coming in at my nodejs application.

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe the problem is when you use: `socket.emit("something else", {hello: "Hello, you are connected"});`

but have this in client-side: `socket.on('data', function(data) {`.

When you emit, you use the channel "something else", but on the client-side you are checking on the channel "data".

So on client-side you should be having `socket.on('something else', function(data){`.

Hope I helped. There isn't much info I could find on sockets.io, so I do not know if there is a preexisting channel called 'data'. Do enlighten me if so :)